# insert to multiple tables using EntityDataSource and DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

With my new site I'm transitioning from my normal n-tiered setup to a Entity framework site using an edmx file and entity data sources.  I have a SiteUsersAdd.aspx page, here's the markup...

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="SiteUserDataSource" runat="server" 
                ContextTypeName="NutritionBridgeModel.NutritionBridgeEntities" 
                EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="SiteUsers" EnableInsert="True" 
                Include="Person" ConnectionString="name=NutritionBridgeEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="NutritionBridgeEntities" >
            </asp:EntityDataSource>
            <asp:EntityDataSource ID="DataUserTypes" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="name=NutritionBridgeEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="NutritionBridgeEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                EntitySetName="SiteUserTypes" Select="it.[SiteUserTypeID], it.[Description]">
            </asp:EntityDataSource>
            <asp:EntityDataSource ID="DataSubscriptionTypes" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="name=NutritionBridgeEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="NutritionBridgeEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                EntitySetName="SubscriptionTypes" 
                Select="it.[Description], it.[SubscriptionTypeID]">
            </asp:EntityDataSource>



            <asp:DetailsView ID="detailsInsertSiteUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SiteUserDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert" CssClass="standardTable" >
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="FirstName"  ControlStyle-CssClass="standardTextbox" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="LastName" ControlStyle-CssClass="standardTextbox" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="Email" ControlStyle-CssClass="standardTextbox" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="Password" ControlStyle-CssClass="standardTextbox" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Type" SortExpression="UserTypeID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader">
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="DataUserTypes" DataTextField="Description" 
                                DataValueField="SiteUserTypeID" CssClass="standardDropdown">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="Active" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subscription Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" SortExpression="SubscriptionTypeID">

                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubscriptionTypes" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="DataSubscriptionTypes" DataTextField="Description" 
                                DataValueField="SubscriptionTypeID" CssClass="standardDropdown">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="TestAccount" HeaderText="Test Account" HeaderStyle-CssClass="rowHeader" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TestAccount" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="standardButton" ItemStyle-CssClass="submitArea" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

I have a persons table and a siteusers table:

PERSONS: PersonID, FirstName, LastName
SITEUSERS: SiteUserID, PersonID, etc..

So when I create a new SITEUSER, I would also like to create a new PERSON.  Is there an elegant way to do this using my entitydatasource?  Does it need to be in the code behind?  If so what does that look like?  So far I'm assuming that it needs to be something like this if it's in the code behind...

```
 Protected Sub detailsInsertSiteUser_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles detailsInsertSiteUser.ItemInserting
        NutritionBridgeContext = New NutritionBridgeEntities

        'insert new person
        Dim intPersonID As Integer = 0

        'use the generated identity field to insert into SiteUser record
        e.Values("PersonID") = intPersonID
    End Sub
```